# Custom rule Form_Validation for school year (Ex: 2001/2002)

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am a newbie

I got a problem, I want to custom rule in form validation for school year

There is an input box, user have to type like this: **2001/2002** or **2013/2014** or **2017/2018** without any exception

In my controller code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_tahun_ajaran','nama_tahun_ajaran','required|max_length[9]|callback_valid_name');

function $valid_name($nama_tahun_ajaran){
// RIGHT HERE I'M STILL Have no Idea to makes a rule
}
```

I hope you understand what I ask
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match the string, then make a simple comparison to ensure the years are within a year of each other and are in the valid order.

```
function valid_name($nama_tahun_ajaran = null)
{
    // Regex patterns for year and forward slash
    $year  = '((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])';
    $slash = '(\\/)';

    // Does the inputted value matche the regex?
    // Checks it's in the form 'year/year'. E.g. '2010/2012'.
    if (preg_match_all("/".$year.$slash.$year."/is", $nama_tahun_ajaran, $matches))
    {
        // Get the years from the string
        $first_year  = $matches[1][0];
        $second_year = $matches[3][0];

        // Is the first year one less than the second year?
        if (($first_year + 1) == $second_year)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }               
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

*This will only work with years in the range 1000-2999.*